# How to use GitHubCommentPush in BuildBot

Tags: python, github, github-api, buildbot

I'm trying to add an automatic feedback from BuildBot to a github pull request using [GitHubCommentPush](http://docs.buildbot.net/current/manual/configuration/reporters.html#githubcommentpush)

But I constantly get an error:

```
2019-07-18 09: 04: 56 + 0000 [-] Timing out client: IPv4Address (type = 'TCP', host = '86 .57.157.184 ', port = 42090)
2019-07-18 09: 04: 56 + 0000 [-] Timing out client: IPv4Address (type = 'TCP', host = '86 .57.245.94 ', port = 42086)
2019-07-18 09: 04: 56 + 0000 [-] Timing out client: IPv4Address (type = 'TCP', host = '86 .57.157.184 ', port = 42092)
2019-07-18 09: 04: 56 + 0000 [-] while invoking <bound method HttpStatusPushBase.buildStarted of <buildbot.reporters.github.GitHubCommentPush object at 0x7f4ae512aa20 >>
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send (result)
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildbot/reporters/http.py", line 80, in getMoreInfoAndSend
            yield self.send (build)
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
            return _cancellableInlineCallbacks (gen)
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
            _inlineCallbacks (None, g, status)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildbot/reporters/http.py", line 80, in getMoreInfoAndSend
            yield self.send (build)
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
            result = g.send (result)
          File "/home/andrei/bot/sandbox/lib/python3.6/site-packages/buildbot/reporters/github.py", line 177, in send
            content = yield response.content ()
        builtins.UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

Apparently my GitHub token is not a valid .

I have no idea what kind of token the buildbot wants.

- I tried to create OAuth Apps (but did not publish it in the GitHub Marketplace) and use the Client Secret of the created application as a token.
- I tried to create GitHub Apps in the same way as above, I used Client Secret as a token.
- I tried to create a Personal access token.

None of these points helped me.

Can anyone explain how this should work?

Here is the code for how I connect the service.

```py
        self.masterConf ['services'] = []
        self.masterConf ['secretsProviders'] = [
            secrets.SecretInAFile (dirname = "/ path / to / buildBotSecret")
        ]

        gc = reporters.GitHubCommentPush (token = util.Secret ("gitHub"),
                                         startDescription = 'Build started.',
                                         endDescription = 'Build done.')

        self.masterConf ['services']. append (gc)
```

Comment: Show your whole configuration file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bug of buildBot version 2.3.1.

Fixed [PR](https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/4907#issuecomment-515323382)

Answer (score 1):

According to code, the error means that we got an exception before creating response variable.

The error management in this code is pretty crappy.
So what I would do is rather to edit the line just before

```
            content = yield response.content()
```

in order to first print the exception details.

Comment: these are buildbot logs, I can’t print the contents of a variable